# merge two object and rename same property

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I have two object which contain some similar properties. I want to merge those two object in one object and also want to rename the similar properties from both objects.

```
var selectedEntity = {"UsageS":"123","DateS":"2016","IsEstimeated":"True"};
var ComapareEntity = {"UsageC":"124","DateC":"2015","IsEstimeated":"False"}

Result = {"UsageS":"123","DateS":"2016","IsEstimeatedS":"True","UsageC":"124","DateC":"2015","IsEstimeatedC":"False"};
```

Please suggest some solution using lodash.

Comment: Object can not have more than one key having same name...

Comment: Thats why I want to rename the key

Comment: Rename the keys to what? Your example contains duplicated keys.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I have edited the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put these two objects in a json array, so that index can used to name duplicate keys

```
   var selectedEntity = {
  "UsageS": "123",
  "DateS": "2016",
  "IsEstimeated": "True"
};
var ComapareEntity = {
  "UsageC": "124",
  "DateC": "2015",
  "IsEstimeated": "False"
}

var toLoopArray = [selectedEntity, ComapareEntity]

var resultantObject = {};
toLoopArray.forEach(function(item, index) {

  for (var keys in item) {
    if (!(resultantObject.hasOwnProperty(keys))) {
      resultantObject[keys] = item[keys]
    } else {
      resultantObject[keys + index] = item[keys]
    }
  }
})
console.log(resultantObject)
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/s93msahu/2/)